# Please explain the use of usedNums[newNum] = true; in the following code

Tags: arrays, random, numbers, boolean, unique

The code below generates the unique random number for bingo card.
The each cell of the HTML table has IDs as square0,square1...square23

I understand the code, except the part below.
"usedNums[newNum] = true;"

Can you please explain the working behind "usedNums[newNum] = true;", what does it actually do in backend?
If I set it to false, the random number generated repeate themselves, and on setting it to true, numbers don't repeat themselves. Why is this happening?

```
window.onload = newCard;
var usedNums = new Array(76);


function newCard() {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        for (var i=0; i<24; i++) {
            setSquare(i);
        }
    }
    else {
        alert("Sorry, your browser doesn't support this script");
    }
}

function setSquare(thisSquare) {
    var currSquare = "square" + thisSquare;
    var colPlace = new Array(0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4);
    var colBasis = colPlace[thisSquare] * 15;
    var newNum;

    do {
        newNum = colBasis + getNewNum() + 1;
    }
    while (usedNums[newNum]);

    usedNums[newNum] = true;
    document.getElementById(currSquare).innerHTML = newNum;
}

function getNewNum() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 15);
}
```

And the HTML for above code is below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Make Your Own Bingo Card</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" rev="stylesheet" href="script.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Create A Bingo Card</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th width="20%">B</th>
        <th width="20%">I</th>
        <th width="20%">N</th>
        <th width="20%">G</th>
        <th width="20%">O</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="square0">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="square1">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="square2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="square3">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="square4">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="square5">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="square6">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="square7">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="square8">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="square9">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="square10">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="square11">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="free">Free</td>
        <td id="square12">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="square13">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="square14">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="square15">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="square16">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="square17">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="square18">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="square19">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="square20">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="square21">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="square22">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="square23">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p><a href="script.html" id="reload">Click here</a> to create a new card</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`usedNums` is an array that tracks which values have already been seen/used.  The do-while loop will repeatedly generate a `newNum` until it comes up with one which hasn't been seen.  Since you will now use this previously unseen value, `usedNums[newNum] = true` records the fact that it has now become part of the `usedNum` set.

Comment: As per my research, array[number] = true; sets all the items in the array to a non zero value, if this is correct, how usedNums[newNum] = true; is keeping track of the previously pushed values.

Please bear with me and explain this in basics, since I am new to javascript.

Thanks!

Comment: Then you've misread or misunderstood your research. The statement `array[number] = true;` sets one and only one element of the array, that element indexed by `number`, to `true`.  It doesn't change any other array elements.

Comment: If it sets one element of the array to true (to a non zero value), then how can this statement check whether the element already exists in the array or not?
Because when I make it to false, the function generates repeating random numbers.

Comment: That statement doesn't check whether the element already exists.  The do-while loop above it is where the checking occurs.  Think of the array as a checklist.  As stated in the answer I gave, the loop will keep generating as long as what gets generated is already on the list.  When it manages to come up with a new value, one which isn't on the list, it adds it to the list so next time this value will also get skipped.  This guarantees no repetition of values. It's less efficient than shuffling the set of values, but it works.

Comment: while (usedNums[newNum]); checks whether the value exists in the array or not, and atleast one value exists, while do-while loop executes the code atleast once irrespective of the condition is true or not.
So, is it correct, that "while(usedNumes[newNum]);" only checks that whether this values exists in the array or not?
And I understand that "usedNums[newNum] = true;" is setting the value for this element in array to true, i.e. a non-zero value, despite this element is already a non-zero value, because code above never generates 0, as we are adding one to it.
How it gurantees non-repeatation

Comment: And can you please paste the code for generating unique random numbers by "shuffling the set of values" method??